# change root account profile picture?

Tags: 13.04

In my ubuntu system, I have two users including root. I tried to change the root user account profile picture. I can't find where it is.

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no separate user named as `root` in Ubuntu. Generally Ubuntu users will be turned to root user when they want by using `sudo -i` command from terminal.

The user you will create for the first in the installation Ubuntu will be the original root user of the Ubuntu Machine you have installed. He can turn into root user with above command I have mentioned.